# Integration testing with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I am working on an application with multiple (10+) containers (microservices .NET, front-end React, 3rd party etc.) being started using docker-compose files.
How would you go about integration testing? Is there a testing framework which would allow a beforeAll() to clear containers, restart them, or clean volumes? Do you know of a well-performing setup to run multiple integration tests against a docker-compose environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use [WatchTower](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/) to update our containers and also the [depends_on](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#depends_on) in our docker-compose.yml.
Hope it helps